# how to move PR2 arm with recorded position trajectory(in joint space)

Tags: ros, pr2-arm-navigation, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 2 seconds long arm movement trajectory which recorded in 10hz(joint space). I want to play this trajectory in pr2 arm. What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38352/how-to-move-pr2-arm-with-recorded-position-trajectory(in-joint-space)/) by [ecalisgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2287/ecalisgan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the action /left_arm_controller/[joint_trajectory_action](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joint_trajectory_action)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/37299/how-to-play-a-joint_state-bag-file/).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2